# kafka consumers registration list in zookeeper

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using C++ kafka lib to produce/consume messages with kafka - everything works great.

Now I want to monitor my consumer to handle disconnections/failure. I'm looking for kind of connection list of all consumers.

from kafka [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#impl_zkconsumerid):

> **Consumer Id Registry**
>
> In addition to the group_id which is shared by all consumers in a
>   group, each consumer is given a transient, unique consumer_id (of the
>   form hostname:uuid) for identification purposes. Consumer ids are
>   registered in the following directory.
>
> ```
> /consumers/[group_id]/ids/[consumer_id] --> {"topic1": #streams, ..., "topicN": #streams} (ephemeral node)
> ```
>
> Each of the consumers in the group registers under its group and
>   creates a znode with its consumer_id. The value of the znode contains
>   a map of `<topic, #streams>`. This id is simply used to identify each
>   of the consumers which is currently active within a group. This is an
>   ephemeral node so it will disappear if the consumer process dies.

But when trying to `ls /consumers` - there's nothing there (my app is up&running and consumers are consume messages via log)

Comment: @Edenhill Is there special tag for `librdkafka` in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2):

The librdkafka high-level KafkaConsumer relies on the new broker-based balanced consumers group in Apache Kafka 0.9 and they dont use ZooKeeper at all.

You can use the `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --new-consumer ..` script in the Kafka distribution to list and describe registered consumer groups.
There is also an API to get this same information programmatically in librdkafka's C interface (`rd_kafka_list_groups()`) and it will be available in the C++ shortly.

Comment: great! can't wait to see it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In kafka 0.9 cluster, only `old-consumers(zookeeper-based offset storage)` are registered under "/consumers/[group_id]/ids/[consumer_id]", `new-consumer(kafka-based offset storage)` does not be registered under "/consumers/[group_id]" path. 
(my cluster version is kafka 0.9.0.1)

Comment: I'm using kafka_2.11.-0.9.0.1. any suggestion how to get the consumers list?